# Why does this always return true? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ran into something weird today.

This function always returns true for some reason, even if there is no title element in the given parent element.

```
// JSEPlaceholder contains "#adiv"
if(typeof $(JSEPlaceholder).children().find("title") !== "undefined"){
  alert();
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you show relevant html?

Comment: What is `JSEPlaceholder`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat states that it's a string in comments

Comment: @RocketHazmat a string that contains "#adiv". So the selector then will be  $("#adiv").something.. This has worked.

Comment: That is not a string. That is an element.

Comment: @A.Sharma "#adiv" isn't a string?

Comment: Correction. It is a string, but it is used as an argument to grab the element object. So yes it is a string representing the element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because jQuery will *always* return you a jQuery object.  It may not contain any elements, but it is still an object.

What you want to do is check its length.

```
if($(JSEPlaceholder).children().find("title").length > 0){
    alert();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

[`$.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) never returns `undefined`. If it finds nothing, it just returns an empty collection.